# material design 2, primary and accent color

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How I can use the same color for the $primary and $accent I have my own custom white color.

```
$mat-white: ( 100: #FFF, 200: #FFF, 300: #FFF, 400: #FFF, 500: #FFF, 600: #FFF, 700: #FFF,
              800: #FFF, 900: #FFF, A100: #FFF, A200: #FFF, A400: #FFF, A700: #FFF,
              contrast: ( 50: $black-87-opacity, 100: $black-87-opacity, 200: $black-87-opacity,
                          300: $black-87-opacity, 400: $black-87-opacity,
                          500: white, 600: white, 700: white, 800: white, 900: white,
                          A100: $black-87-opacity, A200: $black-87-opacity,
                          A400: white, A700: white, ) );
//
```

and to set the colors

```
$primary: mat-palette($mat-white, 600, 100, 800);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-white, 600, 100, 800);
```

Actually I have the black color and white on hover
I want to have the same White color

Comment: in this case, `$primary` and `$accent` both have same colors. Where is the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom set of colors as you did. Here is an example of set of colors from material `_theming.scss`:

```
$your-custom-color-scheme: (
  50: #fce4ec,
  100: #f8bbd0,
  200: #f48fb1,
  300: #f06292,
  400: #ec407a,
  500: #e91e63,
  600: #d81b60,
  700: #c2185b,
  800: #ad1457,
  900: #880e4f,
  A100: #ff80ab,
  A200: #ff4081,
  A400: #f50057,
  A700: #c51162,
  contrast: (
    50: $black-87-opacity,
    100: $black-87-opacity,
    200: $black-87-opacity,
    300: $black-87-opacity,
    400: $black-87-opacity,
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: $white-87-opacity,
    800: $white-87-opacity,
    900: $white-87-opacity,
    A100: $black-87-opacity,
    A200: white,
    A400: white,
    A700: white,
  )
);
```

and then pass it to the definition of `primary | accent | warn`, which is gonna be defined like so:

`$app-primary: mat-palette($your-custom-color-scheme, 600);`

And then passed to the theme mixin like so:

`$theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);`

and then this 'mixed' variable `$theme` will be included to your styles:

`@include angular-material-theme($theme);`